# Error al restar dos fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo esta función para restar la fecha de una multa no pagada, desde esa fecha a la fecha actual. Pero me sale un error

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS finesNotPayed $$
CREATE FUNCTION finesNotPayed (fineDate INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER ;
SET i=(SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(),fineDate) FROM fine);
RETURN i;
END $$
DELIMITER ;



Error code 1292, incorrect datetime value
```

Comment: Tu parametro fineDate no tiene que ser INTEGER, tiene que ser un DATE

Comment: cuál es el motor de base de datos que estás usando?

Comment: @alanfcm , con date he probado y tampoco me funciona

Comment: @Lamak MySQL Workbench

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp

Comment: Por favor, indica qué error sale cuando el parámetro `fineDate` es DATE

Comment: @Alfabravo Error code 1292. Incorrect date value

Answer (score 1):

Las dos variables tienen que ser de tipo DATE para que datediff funcione.  Tambien puedes usar la funcion NOW() asi:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS finesNotPayed $$
CREATE FUNCTION finesNotPayed (fineDate DATE)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
DECLARE i INTEGER ;
SET i=(SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),fineDate) FROM fine);
RETURN i;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Al invocarlo con SELECT finesNotPayed(324) me salé un error de Error code 1292. Incorrect date value. (Es una base de datos con fechas de hace 4 años, por eso he puesto ese número)

Comment: Ese numero no es una fecha.  Para que funcione correctamente tienes que pasar una fecha como parametro.

Comment: Mi idea es poner un número (324) y que devuelva por int los dias de retraso del impago. Es decir, cuantas multas hay después de 324 días, por ejemplo 10 multas sin pagar pasados los 324 días.

Comment: Entonces lo que buscas es la funcion DATE_SUB(): https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp